# Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Promise] at Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, nodejs-server

My problem is as the title of the question is. I am trying to isolate the concerns in my node n express app into separate routes and controllers to keep main server.js file clean.

My project structure is as

```
controller
|---------- controller.js
database
|---------- db.js
route
|---------- players.js
package.json
|
server.js
```

My controller.js is as:

```
const {sql, poolPromise, config}=require('../database/db')
const msnodesqlv8=require('msnodesqlv8');


const getAllPlayers=async(req, res, next)=>
{
    try
    {
        sql.connect(config, function(err)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else
            {
                var request=new sql.Request();

                request.query("select * from players", function(err, recordset)
                {
                    if(err)
                    {
                        console.log("Error while querying: "+err)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.send(recordset);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        res.status(400).send(error.message);
    }
}


module.exports={
    getAllPlayers
}
```

The routes file is:

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const playerControll=require('../controller/controller')

router.get('/players', playerControll.getAllPlayers());


module.exports={
    routes: router
}
```

My main server.js file as:

```
const express = require('express')

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const router=express.Router()
const app = express()
const {poolPromise, config, sql}=require('./database/db')
const playerRoutes=require('./route/players');

app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/api/v1', playerRoutes); <---- attaching to the route file

app.use(morgan('dev'))

app.use(router)

const port=3200;

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port , (err) => {
    if(err)
  console.log('Unable to start the server!')
  else
  console.log('Server started running on : ' + port)
  })
```

On running my app and executing the route localhost:3200/api/v1/players I am getting the error
**Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Promise]     at Route**

Where does this point to? Which file? Can you steer me in the correct direction and help me line up the concerns controller and events properly so that the route /api/v1/players works properly and fetches data. Need help on this. I am unable to decipher the error message. Which object? Need assistance in rectifying the code. I am a complete newbie in node and express and in most glitches like this one I am all at sea.

Thanks

Comment: Use `router.get('/players', playerControll.getAllPlayers)` without the parentheses after `getAllPlayers`, because you register the middleware _function_ at the route, not the promise to which it evaluates.

Comment: hey @HeikoTheißen did it just now; Getting the error:

Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.

Comment: this -->  throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))

Comment: `app.use('/api/v1', playerRoutes.routes)`, not `app.use('/api/v1', playerRoutes)`.

Comment: Yep! Does the trick! @HeikoTheißen    Thanks a ton!!